# TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined at ModuleFederationPlugin.apply

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-5, angular-devkit, webpack-module-federation

I am trying to use Module Federation Plugin in my angular project, but I am getting this error -

```
[error] TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
    at ModuleFederationPlugin.apply (C:\Users\HP\test-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\container\ModuleFederationPlugin.js:45:49)
    at Object.webpack [as webpackFactory] (C:\Users\HP\test-app\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:51:13)
    at createWebpack (C:\Users\HP\test-app\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\webpack-dev-server\index.js:21:36)
    at Object.runWebpackDevServer (C:\Users\HP\test-app\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\webpack-dev-server\index.js:47:12)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.project (C:\Users\HP\test-app\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js:221:32)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (C:\Users\HP\test-app\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:47:27)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\HP\test-app\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:66:18)
    at C:\Users\HP\test-app\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeToPromise.js:7:24
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

My project is requiring two webpacks - **webpack 5 for module federation plugin and webpack@4.44.2 for angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1102.3**.

How to solve this issue? Let me know if you have used the Module Federation plugin in Angular.

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: @Hanggi Yes, I got it solved. Followed this https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/12165

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved using this https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/12165#issuecomment-802947759

Moreover, I found this is resolved in Angular 12. You will not encounter this error using angular 12.